# Strategies for designing REST APIs for all types of client devices

Tags: api, rest

The question is more targeted at server side development.

When writing a REST API, I want to write it in such a way that it can be consumed by both desktop and mobile applications.

Could see two possible approaches:

1. Each API should support pagination and the responsibility should be delegated to the client of how much data should be fetched in one go. So , mobile apps will ask for fewer pages in one go and desktop applications will ask for more.
2. Separate APIs for mobile devices hosted separately. The front-end web server can check the user agent (i.e. source from where is request is coming) and if it's a mobile device, then re-route the request to the server hosting the APIs for mobile devices.

Interested to know more strategies around this.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what would justify maintaining 2 codebases, server stacks, endpoints etc. What's the difference what device type is hitting your API? As you say, you can handle size of payload through parameters on requests. What other considerations are there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a bit of both (1) and (2), here's how.

Instead of re-building whole new api for mobile itself, Have adapters for all the supported devices. i.e have a layer on top of you REST API implementation which renders/instructs the underlying service to return the content suitable for selected mobile device.

coming to pagination, you can parameterize the pagination as an input from the Abstraction mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something closer to option (1). If the main difference between the clients will be the amount of data they request at a time, it seems trivial to add some kind of query parameter or HTTP header to the REST API indicating how many records to return, for instance.

Relying on checking the `User-Agent` header may require you to maintain a list of known client user agents and match against them, which would be an additional maintenance cost of a separate API.